# React: how to update props of root component

Tags: reactjs

I have a React root component mounted on the dom, which receives JSON from the initial page load as props.

After an API call, I want to update that JSON.

I don't know what is the best pattern here, since searching for `Update props on root component` gives me very few results and the #1 page is actually for the Preact lib (not React).

Should I 'clone' the JSON into my root component's  state in the `constructor`, which allows me to change it after the API call via `this.setState` on the root component itself?

The other option I'm aware is calling ReactDOM.render again, but that seems more complex: even tough I could pass all it's current props and the new one as `{...this.props, propsThatWasUpdated }`, I assume the call to `ReactDOM.render()` will reset the component's inner state, which I don't want.

Comment: Should I 'clone' the JSON into my root component's state in the constructor, which allows me to change it after the API call via this.setState on the root component itself?  ---> **YES**

Comment: It is also much better if on page load save it on state directly.

Comment: You could always add a callback which will be provided from parent component

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense there's no parent, it's the root component we're talking about.

Comment: Sorry I misread that. In that case set up something like a redux store.  https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 4):

> I assume the call to ReactDOM.render() will reset the component's inner state, which I don't want.

Actually, this is not the case. At least for the latest version of React.

According to the [ReactDOM documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render):

> If the React element was previously rendered into container, this will perform an update on it and only mutate the DOM as necessary to reflect the latest React element.

So, if you really need to update the props of the root React application component this is a way to go. I would suggest to use this approach only when React is integrated into existing JavaScript application or into some other framework (like Angular).

Here's the helper class I've created to integrate React component into any application:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export class ReactHandler<PropsType> {

  private container: HTMLElement;
  private props: any;


  constructor(private component: typeof React.Component) {
  }

  public get isMounted(): boolean {
    return !!this.container;
  }

  public mount(container: HTMLElement, props?: PropsType) {
    this.ensureUnmounted();
    this.container = container;
    this.props = props;
    this.render();
  }

  public unmount() {
    this.ensureMounted();
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this.container);
    this.container = null;
  }

  public updateProps(props: PropsType) {
    this.ensureMounted();
    Object.assign(this.props, props);
    this.render();
  }


  private render() {
    const componentInstance = React.createElement(this.component, this.props);
    ReactDOM.render(componentInstance, this.container);
  }

  private ensureMounted() {
    if (!this.isMounted) {
      throw new Error(`The component "${this.component.name}" is not mounted`);
    }
  }

  private ensureUnmounted() {
    if (this.isMounted) {
      throw new Error(`The component "${this.component.name}" is already mounted`);
    }
  }

}
```

Call it like this:

```js
// Instantiate the helper
// "Greeter" is a component you are trying to mount
const reactHandler = new ReactHandler<GreeterProps>(Greeter);

// Mount
reactHandler.mount(containerDomElement);

// Update props (partially)
reactHandler.updateProps({ foo: 'foo' });

// Do not forget to unmount or you will cause memory leak!
reactHandler.unmount();
```

Answer (score 1):

It was best if you could have provided some code. Anyway, I would suggest,

1. Call the api in your componentDidMount method.
2. Get the data from the api and set the state with the data(setState())
3. Assign this state as a props to your component

So since the state is changed, react rerenders your child component when ever the data comes from the api with the new data.

Comment: This would make 2 requests to the server, one for the page load another one after componentDidMount. I wished to avoid the extra request.

Comment: There should not be a call before componentDidMount. 
`one for the page load`>> This is from the static server and the web api is from another server, right?

Comment: Nope, it's a Rails application, so it's one request to the web server that generates a view with the JSON data stringified in a <div> (react-rails gem). I eventually decided copying the props of the root component (the ones I'm going to change after the API request) to it's state, and it's working flawlessly, just had to change the related calls to `this.props.` to `this.state`, so that props serve just a initial state setter for the root component.

Answer (score -1):

If your component receives JSON data via props then good place to play around with data is lifecycle method componentWillReceiveProps :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if(this.props !== newProps) {
      // update data or store it in state
    }
}
```